# How to use select() function for both TCP & UDP connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp, udp

I have a functional server code with only TCP connection. Now I want the server to receive from UDP connection. I have used port 2000 for TCP & port 2001 for UDP. Here is a snippet of my code

```
    struct timeval timeout; // timeout for select(), 1ms
    timeout.tv_sec  = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 1000;
    fd_set master; // master file descriptor list
    fd_set read_fds; // temp file descriptor list for select()
    int fdmax; // maximum file descriptor number

    FD_ZERO(&master); // clear the master and temp sets
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);

// TCP port setup
    int sockfd; // listening socket descriptor
    int newsockfd; // newly accept()ed socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen;

    char buf_tcp[256]; // buffer for client data
    char buf_copy_tcp[256];    
    int recv_bytes;

    char remoteIP[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int yes=1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR
    int i, k, rv_getaddrinfo, rv_setsockopt, rv_bind, rv_listen, rv_select;

    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *ptr;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rv_getaddrinfo = getaddrinfo(NULL, "2000", &hints, &servinfo);

    for(ptr=servinfo; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->ai_next) 
    {
        sockfd = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype, ptr->ai_protocol);

        rv_setsockopt = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int));

        rv_bind = bind(sockfd, ptr->ai_addr, ptr->ai_addrlen);

        break;
    }

    if (ptr == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CLI Server error: failed to bind\n\r");
        exit(2);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this

    rv_listen = listen(sockfd, 10);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// UDP port setup
    int sockfd_udp; // listening socket descriptor
    struct sockaddr_storage remoteaddr_udp; // client address
    socklen_t addrlen_udp;

    char buf_udp[256]; // buffer for client data
    char buf_copy_udp[256];    
    int recv_bytes_udp;

    char remoteIP_udp[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    int yes_udp=1; // for setsockopt() SO_REUSEADDR
    int j, rv_getaddrinfo_udp, rv_setsockopt_udp, rv_bind_udp;

    struct addrinfo hints_udp, *servinfo_udp, *ptr_udp;

    memset(&hints_udp, 0, sizeof(hints_udp));
    hints_udp.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints_udp.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    hints_udp.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    rv_getaddrinfo_udp = getaddrinfo(NULL, "2001", &hints_udp, &servinfo_udp);

    for(ptr_udp=servinfo_udp; ptr_udp!=NULL; ptr_udp=ptr_udp->ai_next) 
    {
        sockfd_udp = socket(ptr_udp->ai_family, ptr_udp->ai_socktype, ptr_udp->ai_protocol);

        rv_setsockopt_udp = setsockopt(sockfd_udp, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes_udp, sizeof(int));

        rv_bind_udp = bind(sockfd_udp, ptr_udp->ai_addr, ptr_udp->ai_addrlen);

        break;
    }

    if (ptr_udp == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CLI UDP Server error: failed to bind\n\r");
        exit(2);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo_udp); // all done with this
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    // add the listener to the master set
    FD_SET(sockfd, &master);
    FD_SET(sockfd_udp, &master);

    // keep track of the biggest file descriptor
    if(sockfd > sockfd_udp)
        fdmax = sockfd; // so far, it's this one
    else
        fdmax = sockfd_udp; // so far, it's this one

    do
    {   
        read_fds = master; // copy it

        rv_select = select(fdmax+1, &read_fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);

        // run through the existing connections looking for data to read
        for(i=0; i<=fdmax; i++) 
        {
            if (FD_ISSET(i, &read_fds)) 
            { // we got one!!
                if (i == sockfd) 
                {
                    // handle new connections
                    addrlen = sizeof(remoteaddr);
                    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr, &addrlen);

                    FD_SET(newsockfd, &master); // add to master set
                    if (newsockfd > fdmax)      // keep track of the max
                        fdmax = newsockfd;

                    inet_ntop(remoteaddr.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr), remoteIP, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server: new connection from %s on socket %d\n\r", remoteIP, newsockfd);
                } 
                else if (i == sockfd_udp) 
                {
                    // handle new udp connections
                    addrlen_udp = sizeof(remoteaddr_udp);
                    recv_bytes_udp = recvfrom(i, buf_udp, sizeof(buf_udp), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr_udp, &addrlen_udp); 
                    inet_ntop(remoteaddr_udp.ss_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr*)&remoteaddr_udp), remoteIP_udp, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                    for(j=0; j<=recv_bytes_udp; j++)
                    {
                        if( (buf_udp[k] == '\r') | (buf_udp[k] == '\n') )
                            buf_udp[k] = '\0';
                    }
                    fprintf(stdout, "CLI UDP Server: received %s from connection %s\n\r", buf_udp, remoteIP_udp);
                } 
                else 
                {   // handle data from a client
                    if ((recv_bytes = recv(i, buf_tcp, sizeof(buf_tcp), 0)) <= 0) 
                    {   // got error or connection closed by client
                        if (recv_bytes == 0) // connection closed
                        {
                            fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server: socket %d hung up\n\r", i);
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            perror("CLI Server error: recv");
                            exit(6);
                        }

                        close(i); // bye!
                        FD_CLR(i, &master); // remove from master set
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        for(k=0; k<=recv_bytes; k++)
                        {
                            if( (buf_tcp[k] == '\r') | (buf_tcp[k] == '\n') )
                                buf_tcp[k] = '\0';
                        }
                        fprintf(stdout, "CLI Server: received %s from socket %d\n\r", buf_tcp, i);
                    }
                } // END handle data from client
            } // END got new incoming connection
        } // END looping through file descriptors
    } while(QUIT);
```

I am doing error checking at each stage but didn't include it in the snippet. When I compile & run this, I can connect to port 2000 but not to 2001, my Tera term terminal closes with connection refused message. Why is the client not able to connect to port 2001 (UDP socket) but connects to port 2000 (TCP socket). The server just responds to client messages until client enters QUIT.

I have modeled this code from Beej's Guide to Network Programming selectserver.c code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program that I wrote above was correct but my understanding of socket programming was not. It was a fluke that I managed to write correct code but thanks to @EJP for having an extended discussion in the comments to clear up my doubt.

My mistake was using Teraterm's TCP client to connect to a UDP server. Both communications are mutually exclusive & hence can't communicate with one another. So I had to use a UDP client. Netcat provides an option of UDP client using `netcat -u <ip address> <port>`. Then my UDP server was able to receive messages from UDP client.

Another mistake was confusing bind() with connect() in DATAGRAM sockets. A connected DGRAM is when I use connect on both server & client.

I thought the problem was with select(), as I wrongly thought that UDP & TCP sockets can't be used simultaneously in select(). But the above code is how you write a UDP/TCP server for multiple client.

Thanks again to Beej & @EJP